# Check if Directory is a Mount Point in Objective C in OSX

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, filesystems

I am writing a little command line utility in Objective C which will check if a given path is a mount point, and if not, would mount a network share to it. I was going to write this in bash, but opted to try to learn Objective C instead. I am looking for Objective C equivalent of something like this:

```
mount | grep some_path
```

Basically a function I can use to test if a given path is currently used as a mount point. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `-[NSFileManager mountedVolumeURLs…]` can be used to enumerated all mounted volumes, but I couldn’t find an Objective-C API to mount volumes (they can be unmounted via `-[NSWorkspace unmount…]`. You’d need to use the [Disk Arbitration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework, which exports a C API only. That being said and depending on your requirements, a bash script is probably easier because you wouldn’t have to worry about callbacks and run loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research I ended up using this code, in case any one needs it in the future:

```
        NSArray * keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeURLForRemountingKey, nil];
        NSArray * mountPaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:0];

        NSError * error;
        NSURL * remount;

        for (NSURL * mountPath in mountPaths) {
            [mountPath getResourceValue:&remount forKey:NSURLVolumeURLForRemountingKey error:&error];
            if(remount){
                if ([[[NSURL URLWithString:share] host] isEqualToString:[remount host]] && [[[NSURL URLWithString:share] path] isEqualToString:[remount path]]) {
                    printf("Already mounted at %s\n", [[mountPath path] UTF8String]);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note, the NSURL share is passed into the function as the path to the remote share. Filtering by the remount key gives you a list of mountpoint for remote filesystems, as local filesystems do not have that key set.

Comment: I'm missing some information here - the OP wanted to "mount" if something wasn't already mounted, and I can't see that in your code. Also 'host' and 'share' are not documented in the code - I presume they're both expected to be input arguments of function/method --- could you spare a few more words (maybe an example) of how these can look like? Besides, I'm also interested in local volumes (external drives, disk-on-key, CD's etc. what is the meaning of the "Remount" key then?

Answer (score 1):

in swift:

```
func findMountPoint(shareURL: URL) -> URL?{

    guard let urls = self.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: [.volumeURLForRemountingKey], options: [.produceFileReferenceURLs]) else {return nil}

    for u in urls{

        guard let resources = try? u.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeURLForRemountingKey]) else{
            continue
        }

        guard let remountURL = resources.volumeURLForRemounting else{
            continue
        }

        if remountURL.host == shareURL.host && remountURL.path == shareURL.path{
            return u
        }
    } 

    return nil
}
```